# git: creating a patch that contains blobs

Tags: git

I'm trying to create a patch (that I'll send to someone to apply).
However, I added a couple of image files to the commit.
How do I create a patch that will contain not only the code changes, but also the image file blobs?

Comment: If you're using `git diff` to construct the patch file, you can try including the `--binary` option

Comment: It works. Please post as a comment, and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To output a diff with binary files, include the `--binary` flag to your `git diff` call:

```
git diff --binary
```

**Description:**

```
--binary
  In addition to --full-index, output a binary diff that can be applied
    with git-apply.
```